# Join SQL query Results and Get-ChildItem Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, powershell

**Background:** I have a directory with a number of files that are imported to SQL server.

**Task:** Creating a PowerShell script which will pick up files within this directory and use the filenames as in the SQL query.

**Ultimate objective:** To display SQL results besides the filenames but the resultset being displayed should also show files having no entries in SQL server. Something like `RIGHT JOIN` in SQL server queries.

**Powershell Code**

```Powershell
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) } | Select-Object Name
$Server = "Loadv1"
$DB = "LoadDB"
$dbResults = @()

ForEach ($file in $files)
{
    $fileName = $file.name
    write-host $fileName

    if($fileName.Length -gt 1)
    {
        $Query = "
            SELECT FileName,CurrentStatus 
            FROM LogStatus
            WHERE FileName LIKE '$fileName%'
        "
#       Write-host $Query
    }

    $dbResults += Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $DB -Query $Query
}
$dispResults = $dbResults,$file
$dispResults | Format-Table -autosize
```

**Work done so far:** I have been able to fetch the file names using Get-ChildItem and loop them to get the query results. However, the result I am currently getting does not show the files that don't have corresponding entry in SQL server table

Current Result

```
OperationalLanding20150622061502.dat
OperationalLandingAudit20150622061502.dat
OperativeThird_Party_System20150616090701.dat


FileName                                       CurrentStatus
OperationalLandingAudit20150622061502.dat      SSIS Package Complete
OperativeThird_Party_System20150616090701.dat  SSIS Package Complete
```

Expected Result

```
OperationalLanding20150622061502.dat
OperationalLandingAudit20150622061502.dat
OperativeThird_Party_System20150616090701.dat


FileName                                       CurrentStatus
OperationalLanding20150622061502.dat           NULL
OperationalLandingAudit20150622061502.dat      SSIS Package Complete
OperativeThird_Party_System20150616090701.dat  SSIS Package Complete
```

Hoping I was able to explain my requirement above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so if the SQL query does not have results then NULL is returned and, in essence, nothing is added to the `$dbResults` array. Instead lets append the results to a custom object. I don't know what PowerShell version you have so I needed to do something that I know should work. I also don't use the SQL cmdlets much so I had to guess for some of this.

```psh
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Length -gt 1} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$Server = "Loadv1"
$DB = "LoadDB"

$files | ForEach-Object{
    write-host $_

    $Query = "
        SELECT FileName,CurrentStatus 
        FROM LogStatus
        WHERE FileName LIKE '$_%'
    "
    $Results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $DB -Query $Query

    $props = @{Name = $_}

    If($Results){
        $props.CurrentStatus = $Results.CurrentStatus
    } Else {
        $props.CurrentStatus = "Null"
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props

} | Format-Table -autosize
```

What this does is create a custom object that contains the results of the sql query (Which I did not change for reasons stated above). If there are no results returned we use the string "null" as a filler.

I cleaned up how you generated the `$files` variable by making is a simple string array with `-Expand` and moved the length condition there as well.

You *should* now have all the expected results. I say should since I am assuming what the return object looks like.

Comment: Nice powershell script, clearly I'm more of a sql person and chose not to even touch the powershell :) Very good solution as well

Comment: @PhilipDevine Same goes to you with the technologies in your comment reversed :)

Comment: Thanks Matt !! That worked like charm. Since I am trying to be more functional with more options I'll probably use your solution and develop onto it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Query = "
            SELECT isNull(A.FileName, b.FileName) FileName,ISNULL(A.CurrentStatus,B.CurrentStatus) CurrentStatus 
        FROM LogStatus A
        Right JOIN (SELECT '$filename' FileName,NULL CurrentStatus) B 
        ON a.Filename like '$filename%'

        "
```

This should pad out the filenames for you.  A little tough to prototype since it's in powershell but I might be able to come up with a sql fiddle to prove it.

**EDIT**

Answer edited, with sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12b43/9

Obviously, since you're in a cursor, we can only prove one query at a time.

Comment: Thanks Philip !! I gotta say your SQL solution fit my code perfectly. I wouldn't have to change anything else except the Query but I still went for Matt's solution as I am probably going to explore more on the customobject he created and develop onto it. Thanks again .. This was still a great help :)

Comment: Darn, well glad I could help, it was definitely an interesting problem :)